# Where can I find the list of PGSQL error codes?

Tags: postgresql

I get messages like the following in my application:

> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.  (code: 52461700, sql state:
>   42883, query: SELECT ...

I know where to find the enum for the "sql state" field, but where does the "code" of 52461700 come from?  I searched the PostgreSQL GitHUb mirror for that code in decimal and hex but found nothing.  Is there an enum, header file, table etc. where I can find the list of all reported "code" values?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/errcodes-appendix.html could be a good place to start

Comment: Is this regular PostgreSQL or a fork? I  have never seen an error code like that. Which client are you using?

Comment: Hmm, maybe a fork or a very old version, when I run against a new database on PGSQL 9.2.24 using DbVisualizer (Java 8), I get code: 0 and SQLSTATE: 42883 for an undefined function.  I will dig into the binaries and includes that came with the application server... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from someone who's been here much longer than I have: the numeric code is merely the SQLSTATE, packed into 6-bit encoding, that is, the number code 52461700 can be expanded into the varchar '42883'.  This was a kludge to accommodate certain clients that expected a numeric code rather than a string.  Modern clients like my Java application can use one or the other, but should use the string since that is more standard, and the number doesn't give more detail as I first thought.

I originally posted this question because Googling the number code does turn up a small set of Java and Ruby outputs, but it appears that Laurenz Albe was correct, there is a modified middleware that adds this error code.